# How do you bind a letter key in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, osx-mavericks

A friend has water damage on her keyboard and now <kbd>t</kbd> is not working. The laptop is a MacBook Pro, OS X 10.9. Is there any way for us to re-bind a key for <kbd>t</kbd> and <kbd>T</kbd>? Ideally we would be able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for <kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for <kbd>t</kbd>.

I have tried the [**Mac OS X: How to Create Keyboard Layout and Keybinding**](http://xahlee.info/kbd/osx_keybinding.html) tutorial, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done, here is another question with the answer:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44913/make-a-custom-keyboard-layout-the-system-default-even-for-the-login-screen

This allows you to make a custom keyboard, and place the characters where you like.  But you have to make the file first, and that might require another computer, if you can not type the T character.

Answer (score 0):

Install [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html.en) and save a file like this as `~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::R, VK_CONTROL, KeyCode::T</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::E, VK_CONTROL, KeyCode::T, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then open the KeyRemap4MacBook application, press the ReloadXML button, and enable the setting.

`<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::UK_SECTION, KeyCode::T</autogen>` would change the key above tab on ISO keyboards to T.

You can see key codes with `EventViewer.app`, which is in `/Applications/KeyRemap4MacBook.app/Contents/Applications/`.

See https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en or http://osxnotes.net/keyremap4macbook.html for more information.